# Electron and binary file download

Tags: download, electron, binaryfiles

I'm using electron to wrap a webapp in Windows environment system.
The electron page is a very very simple `win.loadURL()`.

I have this trouble, when I download a binary file from the opened page, the browser asks me where to save the file and then... the page disappears but the process is still running in background windowless and I have to force a closude from task manager.

How can I force to open downloads in a new page leaving the main page opened?